# Opening a .docx file in S3 bucket in Python (Boto3)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

In one of our S3 buckets, we have a .docx file with Mail Merge fields in it.

What I'm trying to do is directly read it directly from the bucket without first downloading it locally!

Typically, I can open a file and see the mail merge fields within it through the use of this code:

```
from mailmerge import MailMerge
document = MailMerge(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\MailMergeFile.docx') # Trying to get a variable to pass in here
print(document.get_merge_fields())
```

As seen above, what I'm trying to do is to get the object in a way where I can just pass it to the MailMerge method, as though I were passing a path on my local machine.

The ways I've looked up to do this haven't been able to work.

```
fileobj = s3.get_object(
    Bucket='bucketname',
    Key='folder/mailmergefile.docx'
    ) 

word_file = fileobj['Body'].read()
contents = word_file.decode('ISO-8859-1') # can't use utf-8 as that gives encoding error

contents
```

But then when I try and pass the `contents` variable to the Mailmerge function, I get another error:

```
document = MailMerge(contents)
print(document.get_merge_fields())
```

The error I get is:
`ValueError: embedded null character`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you are using [docx-mailmerge · PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/docx-mailmerge/).

The documentation is quite sparse but is shows `MailMerge('input.docx')`, which suggests that it is expecting the name of a file, not the 'contents' of a file.

In [looking at the code](https://github.com/Bouke/docx-mailmerge/blob/master/mailmerge.py), it seems to be calling a library to open a zip file.

**Bottom line:** As written, it wants the name of a file, not the contents of the file.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yep - that's the library I'm using. It indeed wants the name of a file, which brings me to my next question - how do I give it the name of a file if the file is in S3, and I can only fetch its contents? The file is private so it's not like I can pass it a url. I'm trying to do all this in memory without downloading anything in a local folder.

Comment: You can't. That library expects to open a file on the local disk system. You will need to `download_file()` and point to that file. (If you are writing an AWS Lambda function, put it in `/tmp/`.) Alternatively, you could modify that library to accept the file contents as being passed-in.

Comment: Understood, thanks a lot for elucidating this for me :) Modifying the library seems like a tad too much trouble so for now I'll just suck it up and work with the file locally.